# Symfony collection form data is not in post params

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

Today our user reported that saving his CV does not work, that it does not save his Skills, languages, driving license level, schools and prev. employments.

That is the Collection forms that i use on 2 parts of website (CV and Offers)...

Funny is that we tested it before going live and running live from IE6 to any other newer browser.

Collections is added correctly using "add foobar record" button, when there is any record in DB it appears in edit correctly, when i edit these existing it will be saved, if i remove them than they will be removed.

But when i add new, these new records is not in Form post data. I cant understand if its part of form, html is rendered correctly,  why it does not include it in post...

These collections works with Offer entity, saved updated added... no problem. i have checked the controller code, the javascript code, the entity code, the html code, the collection templates, the form types..

Here is DB structure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7TnU.png]

here is how i add collection in botz CV and Offer

```
<div class="tbl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">Počítačové znalosti</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="skills" data="0" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'TvarplastTopzamBundle:Collections:SkillCollection.html.twig' with {'form': form.skills.vars.prototype} %}{% endfilter %}">
            {% for skill in form.skills %}
        <div class="row">
                    {% include 'TvarplastTopzamBundle:Collections:SkillCollection.html.twig' with {'form': skill} %}
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(".skills").data("index", {{ loop.index }});</script>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#" class="add_skill_link">Pridať počítačovú znalosť</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem cannot be with entity, because if some relation exists in DB that is displayed as collection, and if its edited, it can be changed or removed, and its displayed in post parameters, then entity, form type, cannot be wrong.

but i handle form like this:

```
public function zivotopisAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $showmsg = false) {

    if (!$this->get("data")->hasPerm(Role::WORKER, $this->getUser())) {
        $message["show"] = true;
        $message["text"] = "Nemáte požadované oprávnenia. Stránka nemôže byť zobrazená.";
        $message["type"] = "box-red";
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($this->renderView("TvarplastTopzamBundle::error.html.twig", array("message" => $message)));
    }

    $return = array();
    $message = array("show" => $showmsg, "type" => "", "text" => "");

    if ($message["show"]) {
        $message["text"] = "Je nutné vyplniť nasledujúce informácie pre pokračovanie.";
        $message["type"] = "box-red";
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if (!is_null($this->getUser()->getZivotopis())) {
        $zivotopis = $em->getRepository("TvarplastTopzamBundle:Zivotopis")->find($this->getUser()->getZivotopis()->getId());
    } else {
        $zivotopis = new \Tvarplast\TopzamBundle\Entity\Zivotopis();
    }

    $originalSkills = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($zivotopis->getSkills()) {
        foreach ($zivotopis->getSkills() as $skill) {
            $originalSkills->add($skill);
        }
    }
    $originalLanguages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($zivotopis->getLanguages()) {
        foreach ($zivotopis->getLanguages() as $language) {
            $originalLanguages->add($language);
        }
    }
    $originalDrivingskills = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($zivotopis->getSkilldriving()) {
        foreach ($zivotopis->getSkilldriving() as $skilldriving) {
            $originalDrivingskills->add($skilldriving);
        }
    }
    $originalEmployments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($zivotopis->getEmployments()) {
        foreach ($zivotopis->getEmployments() as $employment) {
            $originalEmployments->add($employment);
        }
    }
    $originalSchools = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    if ($zivotopis->getSchools()) {
        foreach ($zivotopis->getSchools() as $school) {
            $originalSchools->add($school);
        }
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new \Tvarplast\TopzamBundle\Form\ZivotopisType(), $zivotopis, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('zivotopis'),
    ));


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //var_dump($_POST); die();
        foreach ($originalSkills as $skill) {
            if (false === $zivotopis->getSkills()->contains($skill)) {
                $skill->getZivotopis()->removeElement($zivotopis);
                $em->persist($skill);
                $em->remove($skill);
            }
        }
        foreach ($originalLanguages as $language) {
            if (false === $zivotopis->getLanguages()->contains($language)) {
                $language->getZivotopis()->removeElement($zivotopis);
                $em->persist($language);
                $em->remove($language);
            }
        }

        foreach ($originalDrivingskills as $drivingskill) {
            if (false === $zivotopis->getSchools()->contains($drivingskill)) {
                $drivingskill->getZivotopis()->removeElement($zivotopis);
                $em->persist($drivingskill);
                $em->remove($drivingskill);
            }
        }
        foreach ($originalEmployments as $employment) {
            if (false === $zivotopis->getEmployments()->contains($employment)) {
                $employment->getZivotopis()->removeElement($zivotopis);
                $em->persist($employment);
                $em->remove($employment);
            }
        }
        foreach ($originalSchools as $school) {
            if (false === $zivotopis->getSchools()->contains($school)) {
                $school->getZivotopis()->removeElement($zivotopis);
                $em->persist($school);
                $em->remove($school);
            }
        }

        $zivotopis->upload();
        $zivotopis->setBasicUser($this->getUser());
        $zivotopis = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($zivotopis);
        $em->flush();

        $message["text"] = ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_WORKER') ? "Životopis" : "Profil") . " bol úspešne uložený.";
        $message["type"] = "box-yellow";
        $message["show"] = true;
    }

    $return["form"] = $form->createView();
    $return["message"] = $message;
    return $return;
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.extend({getDeleteLinkCode: function(div) {
            return '<div class="col" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 3px;"><a href="#" style="margin-top: 5px;" >Odstrániť</a></div>';
        }});

    $.extend({addSubFormSelectChangeListener: function(collectionHolder, formRow, div) {
            formRow.find('select' + (!div ? ':first' : '')).on("change", function() {
                var org = $(this);
                if (collectionHolder.find(!div ? "tr" : "div").size() > 1) {
                    collectionHolder.find(!div ? "tr" : "div").each(function() {
                        if (org.val() === $(this).find('select:first').val() && org.attr("id") !== $(this).find("select:first").attr("id")) {
                            org.parent().parent().remove();
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        }});

    $.extend({addSubForm: function(collectionHolder, div) {
            var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');
            var index = collectionHolder.data('index');
            index = (index !== parseInt(index) ? 0 : index);
            var form = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
            var formRow = $((div ? '<div class="row"></div>' : '<tr></tr>')).append(form);
            var removeFormRow = $($.getDeleteLinkCode(div));
            formRow.append(removeFormRow);
            collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
            collectionHolder.append(formRow);
            removeFormRow.on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                formRow.remove();
            });
            $.addSubFormSelectChangeListener(collectionHolder, formRow, div);
        }});


    function addSubFormItemDeleteLink(collectionHolder, $tagFormLi, div, notag) {
        var $removeFormA = $($.getDeleteLinkCode(div));
        $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);
        $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $tagFormLi.remove();
        });
        $.addSubFormSelectChangeListener(collectionHolder, $tagFormLi, div);
    }

    jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function(show) {
        $(this).toggle(show);
        if (show) {
            if ($(this).parent('span.toggleOption').length) {
                $(this).unwrap();
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).parent('span.toggleOption').length === 0) {
                $(this).wrap('<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />');
            }
        }
    };

    $.extend({comboFilter: function(inputField, comboBox) {
            $("#" + inputField).delayBind("input", function() {

                var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                var combobox = document.getElementById(comboBox);

                $("#" + comboBox).children("span").children("optgroup").each(function() {
                    $(this).toggleOption(true);
                });


                optionToSelect = false;

                $("#" + comboBox + " option").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/<.+?>/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").indexOf(inputValue.replace(/<.+?>/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")) !== -1) {
                        optionToSelect = $(this);
                        $(this).toggleOption(true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).toggleOption(false);
                    }
                    if (optionToSelect !== false) {
                        $(optionToSelect).select();
                    }
                });


                $("#" + comboBox).children("optgroup").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).children("option").length <= 0) {
                        $(this).toggleOption(false);
                    } else {
                        $(this).toggleOption(true);
                    }
                });

                if ($("#" + comboBox).children("optgroup").length <= 0) {
                    $("#" + comboBox).children("span").children("optgroup").children("option").each(function() {
                        $(this).parent().toggleOption(true);
                    });
                }

                if (inputValue === '') {
                    combobox[0].selected = true;
                    $("#" + comboBox).children("span").children("optgroup").each(function() {
                        $(this).toggleOption(true);
                    });
                }


            }, 50);
        }});


    /* skills */
    holderSkills = $('div.skills');
    holderSkills.find('div.row').each(function() {

        addSubFormItemDeleteLink(holderSkills, $(this), false, false);
    });

    $(".add_skill_link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.addSubForm(holderSkills, true);
    });

    /* driving */
    holderDriving = $('div.skilldriving');
    holderDriving.find('div.deletehere').each(function() {
        addSubFormItemDeleteLink(holderDriving, $(this), true, true);
    });
    $(".add_driving_link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.addSubForm(holderDriving, true);
    });

    /* Lang */
    holderLanguages = $('div.languages');
    holderLanguages.find('div.row').each(function() {
        addSubFormItemDeleteLink(holderLanguages, $(this), false, false);
    });
    $(".add_lang_link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.addSubForm(holderLanguages, true);
    });

    /* Emp */
    holderEmployments = $('div.employments');
    holderEmployments.find('div.deletehere').each(function() {
        addSubFormItemDeleteLink(holderEmployments, $(this), false, false);
    });
    $(".add_zam_link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.addSubForm(holderEmployments);
    });

    /* Schools */
    holderSchools = $('div.schools');
    holderSchools.find('div.deletehere').each(function() {
        addSubFormItemDeleteLink(holderSchools, $(this), false, false);
    });
    $(".add_Schools_link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.addSubForm(holderSchools);
    });


});
```

Any idea where can the problem be?
Thank you very much

Comment: SP thanks for edit, i had no reputation to be able to post image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Dynamically added form field not showing up in POSTed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031340/dynamically-added-form-field-not-showing-up-in-posted-data)

Solved by switching first 2 lines to be {form} first and div the second

i had something like

```
<div .....>
{form....}

some html

</div>
<div>

htmlhhtml

</div>
</div>
{endform}
```

That was the reason why browser was not able to read newly added items